Is a curve on a finite interval always bounded?
Is it true that the image of a parametric curve $\gamma: I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $I$ is one of $[a;b]$, $(a;b)$, $[a;b)$ and $(b;a]$, is always contained in some open ball with a finite radius? How would one go about proving this?

What about $\gamma(t) = (t,1/t)$ on $(0,1)$?

Presumably you mean "is the image of $\gamma$ contained in some open ball around the origin."

It is true if the interval is bounded and closed (the continuous image of a compact set is compact).
It is not true if the interval has some open ending. Ethan Bolker's example shows it.

Thank you for the answer, just what I was looking for. I am assuming proving this requires diving into topology?

Also, is the inverse true, i.e. is it true that all parameterisations of a curve contained within an open ball have a closed and bounded interval as their domain?

Of course not. Take for instance $f(t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$ for $t\in[0,2\pi)$. The trick is that $\lim\limits_{t\to2\pi} f(t)=f(0)$.

Oops, sorry, I phrased my question in the wrong way. What I meant to ask was, if a curve $\mathcal{C}$ has a paremeterisation on a closed and bounded interval, then does every parameterisation of $\mathcal{C}$ have a closed and bounded interval as its domain?

Again, of course not. Take $f(t)=(t, 0)$ for $t\in[0,1]$. Take now $g(x)=(t,0)$ for $t\in[0,1/2)$ and $g(t)=(t-1,0)$ for $t\in[3/2,2]$. Then $f$ and $g$ have the same image but $f$ has a compact domain and $g$ deos not.

But in this case the domain of $g$ is not a single interval and so it is, by definition, not a curve parameterisation. The definition I have for a curve is that a curve is the image of a continuous function $\gamma: I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined on an interval $I$ and that a curve parameterisation is any function which satisfies those conditions and whose image is the curve.
